# How to create training dataset(images) of three different types of images who each have different types of name(in python)?

Tags: python, deep-learning

I am a novice deep learning practitioner. I am working on a problem with a dataset that has 3 different categories. I want to categorize them and put them in a folder so I can train my model on them. The 3 categories are Dog face, Dog body, Dog tail. I have used the following code to print all of the image names.I want to create a file for each of category that contains only the images with a particular suffix such as all the images with face as suffix are in one folder and same for others. I hope someone can help me with some concrete code or some useful material. Thank you in advance

```
    import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for filename in files:
      if filename.endswith(".png"):

        print(filename)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use dictionaries:

```
import os
d = {'Dog face': [], 'Dog body': [], 'Dog tail': []}
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(".png"):
            if 'face' in filename:
                d['Dog face'].append(filename)
            elif 'body' in filename:
                d['Dog body'].append(filename)
            elif 'tail' in filename:
                d['Dog tail'].append(filename)
```